# Tinymce and best method for filtering input

Tags: php, security, mysqli, tinymce

I am planning on using Tinymce but I am a little stumped on the security issues it will bring as I will be allowing logged users to create blogs on the site.

I will be allowing them to place image sources and URL links so they can link stuff to other websites to create a better blog and experience for the reader and possibly allow them to add a embedded video if it is not to hard to accomplish on a safe scale.

I understand that i am able to use `mysqli_real_escape_string` but I am unsure whether that will effect image sources and URL links and what security risks come with using `mysqli_real_escape_string` if it does allow users to insert images and URLs.

Is there better methods out there to get the service that I would like to give my writers and readers of the blogs that are created.

I understand that there will always be a certain degree of a security issue if I allow logged users to create blogs but I am unsure what levels of security I should use and the effects it will have on the finished blog.

Thanks for you time.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/).

You should also consider converting your code from mysqli to PDO for better security.

Comment: i wasn't actually aware of PDO until a few hours before you write this answer. I am going to have a good look into PDO as security is something that I want to be able to build while I build my site. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: I have decided to use HTMLENTITIES at this moment in time however i am running a preg replace to remove any unwanted <script> tags before it is ran though the entities code. I will post my code here when I have  a solid answer for my question but that will not be until tomorrow as I need to check a few things with the preg replace